# Custom exception after DML

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a try-catch block in @AuraEnabled method:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void doTest(String opportunityId) {
    try {
        Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(
            Id = opportunityId
        );

        update opportunity;
        throw new CustomException('test');
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Update doesn't work for some reason. But it works if I comment throwing exception:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void doTest(String opportunityId) {
    try {
        Opportunity opportunity = new Opportunity(
            Id = opportunityId
        );

        update opportunity;
        // throw new CustomException('test');
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why?

Comment: It what way does it not work? Are you expecting the update to be rolled back due to the subsequent exception?

Comment: I expected that update wouldn't be rolled back, but opportunity is updated only if I comment exception. And in VF controller is works as I expect.
Maybe the reason is that @AuraEnabled is static?

Comment: Is there anything else occurring  in the AruaEnabled method before it returns? In particular, anything that would have caused it to exit on an exception.

Comment: No, I see my custom exception in console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior. If an transaction is terminated by an exception then any preceding DML that occured in that transaction will be rolled back.

In your case it is the unhandled `AuraHandledException` that is causing the rollback of the update DML on the Opportunity record.

If `CustomException` wasn't caught it would also cause this rollback of the Opportunity update.

See [Exceptions in Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_exception_definition.htm): (My emphasis)

> ## What Happens When an Exception Occurs?
>
> When an exception occurs, code execution halts. **Any DML operations that were processed before the exception are rolled back and aren’t committed to the database.** Exceptions get logged in debug logs. For unhandled exceptions, that is, exceptions that the code doesn’t catch, Salesforce sends an email that includes the exception information. The end user sees an error message in the Salesforce user interface.

Comment: In case of VF controller, I just displayed a message on the page instead of throwing AuraHandledException in catch block, so it worked without any problems. Now it's clear. Thank you!